# how to make html div edge with slope?

Tags: html, css

my current HTML & CSS are like: 
[image]

I want to make this like:
[image]

How can I do this?...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `rotate` and `skew` transforms. Positive angle will result in clockwise transform for both rotate and skew so you want to use negative angle in this case.

```css
.element {
  margin: 40px;
}
.element>div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  transform: rotate(-10deg) skew(-10deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <div style="background: red"></div>
  <div style="background: blue"></div>
  <div style="background: green"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution without the use of transform is to rely on gradient:

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(160deg, transparent 0, transparent 20%,
                                    red 20%,red 40%,
                                    green 40%,green 60%,
                                    blue 60%,blue 80%,
                                    transparent 0);
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<div style="background: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; transform: rotate(-4deg);"></div>
```

If you want to rotate in clockwise direction pass the angle value in positive. If you want it to rotate anti-clockwise pass the values in negative.

Answer (score 0):

`transform: skewY();` is your friend. Try this code.

```
<div id="red">
  <div class="inner">
    red
  </div>
</div>
<div id="green">
  <div class="inner">
    green
  </div>
</div>
<div id="blue">
  <div class="inner">
    blue
  </div>
</div>

#red {
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  padding: 50px 0;
}

#green {
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  padding: 80px 0;
}

#blue {
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.inner {
  transform: skewY(5deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 380px;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  transform: skewY(-10deg);
}

#red{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="background: red" id="red" class="box"></div>
  <div style="background: green" class="box"></div>
  <div style="background: blue" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to achieve this using the 2D transform CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

To rotate the `div`s all you need to do is add `transform: rotate(30deg);` to their styles.